# Using wildcards in VBA cells.replace

Tags: excel, ip-address

I'm looking to write a function in Excel to add leading zeroes to the octets that make up an IP address: e.g in 172.19.1.17 I want to to change .19. to .019., the .1. to .001., and the .17 at the end to .017.

Te Cells.Teplace function does not seem to accept ? as a wildcard. Also, is there a way I can represent 'end of string' so I'll be able to add leading zeroes to the last octet, .17 in the example above.

Thanks Ian

```
Cells.Replace What:=".1?.", Replacement:=".01?.", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

This does find "10." "11." "12." etc. but replaces them all with ".01?."

Comment: Unlike Word, Excel Search And Replace does *not* support wildcards.

Comment: It does in the find part pof the function; and heres the help text:In the Find what box, type the text or numbers that you want to search for, or click the arrow in the Find what box, and then click a recent search in the list. 
You can use wildcard characters, such as an asterisk (*) or a question mark (?), in your search criteria:

Use the asterisk to find any string of characters. For example, s*d finds "sad" and "started". 
Use the question mark to find any single character. For example, s?t finds "sat" and "set".
Tip  <snip>

Comment: @Ian. Yes, you can use wildcard in the Find function. For example if you want to find all cells where octets are like `.??.` then you can use `".??."` in your search. I would recommend using `.Find` and `.FindNext` together to find such instances and then use a UDF to replace those characters. Let me know if you need an example. This should get you going... http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative you may use this formula to add zeros to IP parts (it looks terrible, but treats separately all the parts and finally mix them up):

```
=REPT(0,4-FIND(".",A1))&LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1)&"."&
REPT(0,4-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","@",2))+FIND(".",A1))&MID(A1,FIND(".",A1)+1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","@",2))-FIND(".",A1)-1)&"."&
REPT(0,4-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","@",3))+FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","@",2)))&MID(A1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","@",2))+1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","@",3))-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","@",2))-1)&"."&
REPT(0,3-LEN(A1)+FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","@",3)))&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","@",3)))
```

You may paste it as it is to `B1` (assuming your IPs are in column A starting `A1`) regardless line breaks.

Sample file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vun6urvukch9uvv/IPoctets.xlsx

Comment: + 1 :) The only drawback that I see with formulas is that if the data is spread all over then the user will have a tough time implementing it. Of course the formula can be converted into a VBA code and then it will work for any cell in the worksheet :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout agree entirely. Anyway, pure Excel solution for this is hardly possible - as you noted. And most likely it is so - I'd use Word with its regex-like replace routine (e.g. as Maks recommended there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14881215/2052209) if I had a column of IPs.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Damn it, but it's true))) I pray for Microsoft to power up Excel search one day with this...)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

Be sure to replace Application.UsedRange with the actual range containing the IP addresses

```
Sub PadIP()
    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim ipAddr As String
    Dim vCell As Variant
    Dim n As Long

    'Replace ActiveSheet.UsedRange with the range containing your data
    '
    'If data is contained in column A and you have a column header
    'Example: Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1))
    For Each vCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        Arr = Split(vCell.Value, ".")

        For n = 0 To UBound(Arr)
            If (n + 1) Mod 4 = 0 Then
                ipAddr = ipAddr & Right(String(3, "0") & Arr(n), 3)
            Else
                ipAddr = ipAddr & Right(String(3, "0") & Arr(n), 3) & "."
            End If
        Next
       vCell.Value = ipAddr
       ipAddr = ""
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 for the concept. Just needs error handling in case "." is missing. I know you said `Replace ActiveSheet.UsedRange with the range containing your data` but like I said Just in Case :)

Answer (score 1):

Can I play too :)?

This is further to my comment above. This is an example on how to find `.??.` and make it `.0??.`

I am assuming that the data can be **ANYWHERE** in the worksheet.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim oRange As Range, aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ExitLoop As Boolean
    Dim SearchString As String

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set oRange = ws.Cells

    SearchString = ".??."

    Set aCell = oRange.Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Set bCell = aCell

        aCell.Value = CleanIt(aCell.Value)

        Do While ExitLoop = False
            Set aCell = oRange.FindNext(After:=aCell)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                aCell.Value = CleanIt(aCell.Value)
            Else
                ExitLoop = True
            End If
        Loop
    End If
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub

Function CleanIt(rng)
    Dim MyAr() As String
    Dim strTemp As String

    MyAr = Split(rng, ".")

    For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
        If Len(MyAr(i)) = 2 Then
            MyAr(i) = "0" & MyAr(i)
        End If
        strTemp = strTemp & "." & MyAr(i)
    Next i
    CleanIt = Mid(strTemp, 2)
End Function
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

**NOTE**: This is just an example for demonstration purpose. The above code needs to be tweaked more so that it can handle other scenarios as well.

Comment: Will it handle `127.0.0.1`? ;)

Comment: @PeterL. You missed few things on my post ;) 1.  This is an example on how to find .??. and make it .0??. AND 2) See the Note in the end

Comment: oh I see then - OP still has the possibility to learn) This is missing in my solution)))

Comment: @PeterL.: I didn't want to post an answer so I gave OP a link to follow but when I saw so many replies, I thought, I'll `play` too ;)

Comment: for me that was a nice practice too - were times these left/mid/right games were my favorite)